# Display UIActionSheet in iphone the same as ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactionsheet

I have a a UIButton, and I would like to add a UIActionSheet.

How can I make the iphone version look like so:

[image]

If there is a way of doing it another way, meaning not with UIActionSheet, I'm open to hear other ways.

Hope I was clear enough. If you have questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in a native way in iOS8 only with the following

```
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverController = [[UIPopoverPresentationController alloc] init];
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 160);
[popOverController setDelegate:self];

popOverController.sourceView = self.view;
popOverController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
popOverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

[self presentViewController:popOverController
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
```

you can use one of custom controls from [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) for iOS7 support

Good luck

Comment: What is pickerController at the first line? I got a error for that

Comment: I get an error at 'popoverContentSize' and at 'presentViewController:popOaverController'